# Dynamically initialize variables (radio button values) in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let's say I am designing a quiz with multiple-choice questions. The number of option for each question can vary. How do I name the variable dynamically? eg. Normally what we do in python is

```
_radValue+str(index) = -1
```

can we have something like this in dart?

For known number of radio buttons the code I generally use is:

```
  int _radioValue1 = -1;
  int _radioValue2 = -1;
  int _radioValue3 = -1;
```

Radio Button Widget goes like:

```
Column(children:
          List<Widget>.generate(
            widget.items,
                (int j) => Row(
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                widget.members,
                    (int i) => Radio<int>(
                  value: i,
                  groupValue: groupValue,
                  onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
}

  void _handleRadioValueChange(int value) {
    setState(() {
      groupValue = value;
    });
  }
```

I can generate a dynamic number of radio buttons by wrapping the generated list of radioButtons. I am just not able to generate

```
_radioValue+(index).toString() = -1;
```

please help! thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dart doesn't have a concept of dynamic variable names. Use an array of values, and generate the radio button widgets dynamically, with values 0, 1, 2, etc. For example:

```
class RadioSet extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> questions;

  RadioSet(this.questions);

  @override
  _RadioSetState createState() => _RadioSetState();
}

class _RadioSetState extends State<RadioSet> {
  int groupValue = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: List<Widget>.generate(
        widget.questions.length,
        (int i) => Radio<int>(
              value: i,
              groupValue: groupValue,
              onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange,
            ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleRadioValueChange(int value) {
    setState(() {
      groupValue = value;
    });
  }
}
```

Incidentally, each `Radio` has fixed, different `value`, with selected one being the one who's value matches the group value.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help. It works for selecting a single value for sure. Can you please help with one more thing? I am trying to draw 10 such questions, let's say for now, all have 4 options. If I generate list of rows as you mentioned, when I select the 1st radio button, values of all 1st radio buttons is updated, which is obvious, can you please help with that? the output looks like [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zQpAFytes8vcoXSYPMu7mJ_luT-aGi20/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: I have edited the code accordingly in the question, thank you!

Comment: change value to `value: j * 10 + i,` which will number the first of radios 0, 1, 2,... and the next row 10, 11, 12,...